# How to sum total json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to count total sum for each column:
My code is simply get data row by row and put it to final array.
The problem is here that I don't know how to handle this array in array and moreover count total sum for each column

```
$.each(data, function(rowNum, rowValue) {
let row = [];
$.each(rowValue, function(cellNum, cellValue) {
    ws_row.push(cellValue.qText);
    });
    console.log('row: ' + row)
    ws_data.push(row);
    });
```

Data

```
console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data))
```

```
[
  [
    {
      "qText": "-",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": -2,
      "qState": "L",
      "qIsNull": true
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "4444376003694.462000000000000000",
      "qNum": 4444376003694.462,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "qText": "5",
      "qNum": 5,
      "qElemNumber": 7,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "578565786417.105600000000000000",
      "qNum": 578565786417.1056,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "qText": "3.3",
      "qNum": 3.3,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "38846991554.611330000000000000",
      "qNum": 38846991554.61133,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "qText": "3",
      "qNum": 3,
      "qElemNumber": 9,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "33036337251.042200000000000000",
      "qNum": 33036337251.0422,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "qText": "3.6",
      "qNum": 3.6,
      "qElemNumber": 5,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "31437556611.191444000000000000",
      "qNum": 31437556611.191444,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "qText": "3.2",
      "qNum": 3.2,
      "qElemNumber": 4,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "13104541271.185572000000000000",
      "qNum": 13104541271.185572,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ]
]
```

Right now I get rows:

[image]

My expected result:

1. Create new rows for total sum, and also sum should be only for even numbers

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To ho toto to sum json ho to ho hoho!

Comment: @MarianTheisen danke sehr :)

Comment: Could you add the expected output *literally* (for the same JSON)?

Comment: Your js snippet seems to lack some context based on variable declarations missing.
Also please clarify your desired outcome more clearly. The sentence doesnt indicate exactly what val you want summed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need the decimals or not but the blow code **will not take into account the decimals** (based on your image where the numbers were just `int` types, without all the decimals..) You can start something from here..

What I did was to take only the last object from each sub-array `rowValue[2].qNum`, transformed it to `int` and check if the number is even, if yes, I add it to `total` and return it..

Note that I don't know how the last row data should look like, I just supposed the format..

```js
let data = [
  [{
      "qText": "-",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": -2,
      "qState": "L",
      "qIsNull": true
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "4444376003694.462000000000000000",
      "qNum": 4444376003694.462,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "qText": "5",
      "qNum": 5,
      "qElemNumber": 7,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "578565786417.105600000000000000",
      "qNum": 578565786417.1056,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "qText": "3.3",
      "qNum": 3.3,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "38846991554.611330000000000000",
      "qNum": 38846991554.61133,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "qText": "3",
      "qNum": 3,
      "qElemNumber": 9,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "33036337251.042200000000000000",
      "qNum": 33036337251.0422,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "qText": "3.6",
      "qNum": 3.6,
      "qElemNumber": 5,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "31437556611.191444000000000000",
      "qNum": 31437556611.191444,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "qText": "3.2",
      "qNum": 3.2,
      "qElemNumber": 4,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "Values",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "13104541271.185572000000000000",
      "qNum": 13104541271.185572,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ]
]


function isEven(value) {
  return value % 2 ? true : false;
}

function getTotalOfEvenValues(data) {
  let total = 0;
  $.each(data, function(rowNum, rowValue) {
    let intValue = Math.floor(rowValue[2].qNum) // rowValue[2] only if the data will have the same format always..with the value you need in the 3rd object
    console.log(intValue + ' isEven ' + isEven(intValue))
    if (isEven(intValue)) {
      total += intValue;
    }
  });
  return total; // use this total to place it in your new row
}

function addRowToData() {
  const totalOfEvenQNum = getTotalOfEvenValues(data);
  // i don't know how the empty rows should look like behind so i am just guessing the format.. but the last object should look like that
  data.push([{
      "qText": "",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": "",
      "qNum": "NaN",
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "O"
    },
    {
      "qText": totalOfEvenQNum.toString(),
      "qNum": totalOfEvenQNum,
      "qElemNumber": 0,
      "qState": "L"
    }
  ])
}

console.log('total for qNum ' + getTotalOfEvenValues(data));
addRowToData()
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```